# Mercurial and SVN workflow issue

Tags: svn, mercurial

I have an interesting source control workflow problem.

My company is working with a third party contractor that is using SVN to track a product that is currently in active development.  We will be taking over this repository within the next few months, but we would like to start work on other functionality within the project.  For obvious reasons, our contractor has denied us commit access, but agreed to read access to their SVN repo.

For our windows development machines, we use a mercurial repository.  **I would like to somehow copy the SVN repo to a new HG repo and periodically merge changes committed to SVN into HG.**  In other words, we will be working side-by-side in two different repositories.

Has anyone done anything like this?  Any suggestions on an approach?

Thanks.

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion

Comment: Thanks.  I actually decided to just manually merge for now.  I created the new repo in HG, and I will periodically manually copy files from svn.  I would love to hear from anyone else if they have suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine any process would only get worst as your changes in mercurial increase and get further apart from the changes in SVN that are never merging with your mercurial changes.  However, I would be curious to see how mercurial merges fair with that complexity.  I would approach it this way:

1) Export from svn to create your hg repo, lets call this `/SvnExportCleanHG`
Clone that to a working copy where all new features from your company will go: `/WorkingHG`

2) When you want to pull in new changes from SVN, do a svn update from `/SvnExportCleanHG` and commit this to the clean repo.  This will have 2 revisions now, original and latest from svn.  From within `/WorkingHG` run an `hg pull /SvnExportCleanHG` and merge all the inevitable changes.  Then commit that to the WorkingHG repo.

Now you have tried to use mercurials merging to the best of your ability and you still have a clean `/SvnExportCleanHG` that you can pull the next change from SVN without any conflicts.

Anytime you want to update from svn again, do step 2. Updating from svn and committing in the clean repo will never conflict because it will only reflect svn, but it will always allow you to pull and merge from your working copy HG because they are based the same.

It depends on the level of your changes and the changes from SVN if mercurial merging will buy you much.  If you guys stay in different baselines of the code, this will be a great workflow and save a lot of manual effort.  If you are overlapping heavily, this will still work, but it will simply facilitate your workflow as opposed to solve many merging issues.

I would be really interested in how this works out if you ever try it.

Comment: This makes so much sense.  I wish that I would have thought of this approach when I first encountered the problem!  Although it is no longer an issue for me, I am glad that you answered this for posterity and my sanity.

Answer (score 0):

SVN + Mercurial work good until you start merging. But why do you need mercurial if you don't use merging. We had almost such situation. We made svn copy to mercurial using hgsubversion extension and all active development is in mercurial now. then time from time we just copy mercurial working directory to svn without history and all branches.